# summing elements in a list of lists

Tags: python

I have a list like:

```py
[array([ 0.6,  0.6, -0.6, -0.6, -0.6, -0.6, -0.6, -0.6, -0.6, -0.6]), array([ 0.35,  0.35,  0.35,  0.35,  0.35,  0.35,  0.35,  0.35, -0.35,
       -0.35])]
```

and I can guarantee that each sublist is the same size. I need to sum every element at each position (producing one list of the same size as the sublists).

This is generated like this:

```py
    sums = []
    for key in est_dict.keys():
        model, alpha = est_dict[key]

        fX = model.predict(X)
        y_fx = np.where(fX==0, -1, fX)
        sums.append(y_fx * alpha)
```

if there's a way to build the sum immediately, without knowing the size of the sublists in advance, that would be even better.

Comment: Why do you have a list of numpy arrays rather than a 2D array?

Comment: `res = np.vstack(sums).sum(axis=0)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`np.sum(sums, axis=0)`

You even don't need to create a new 2D numpy array.